# sql replace function that matches whole words

Tags: sql, pervasive

I wish to replace some text within a field, so i have the following statement:

```
UPDATE INVENTORY
SET INV_DESCRIPTION = REPLACE(INV_DESCRIPTION, '5 ml', '5ml (1/6oz)')
```

The problem lies in the fact that this statement will replace strings such as '5 ml' '15 ml' '150 ml' etc, with the replacement string.  I wish for this function to match the whole word and just look for '5 ml'

Comment: which database software are you using? In Oracle regexp_replace would accomplish what you want.

Comment: What does the whole field (INV_DESCRIPTION) you are trying to update look like? Is it consistent?

Comment: HI there Samuel its called 'Pervasive'

Comment: Is this for BusinessVision?  AccPac uses Pervasive too, but...

Comment: @OMG - Pervasive tools also use it, unfortunately.  I use some of  their other tools but not the SQL implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `WHERE` clause which should get you pretty close:

```
...Your Current Query...
WHERE INV_DESCRIPTION LIKE '5ml%'
OR INV_DESCRIPTION LIKE '% 5ml%'
```

Which will only update records that start with `5ml` or have `5ml` with a space before it, which would exclude `15ml` or `25ml`, etc.

This is assuming SQL Server.