# Replace a word in SQL in comma separated list

Tags: sql, replace

I have a varchar column in SQL table containing some words separated by comma like:

```
Col1
man,woman,cat
dog,man,cat
dog,cat,woman,man
```

and I need to replace some word with another, let's say replace "man" to "boy"

But I'd need to avoid situation when "man" is replaced as part of another word - "woman" becomes "woboy"

How to do it in SQL?

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Col1=??? WHERE ???
```

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are storing lists properly, in a junction table.

Comment: This question has already been answered: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497074/sql-replace-function-that-matches-whole-words

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm sure that there are better ways, but this works (for SQL Server):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET col1 = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(',' + col1 + ',',',man,',',boy,'),2,
                     LEN(REPLACE(',' + col1 + ',',',man,',',boy,'))-2)
WHERE ',' + col1 + ',' LIKE '%,man,%';
```